# Answer in meta deleted because it was unpopular?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170304) <del>(10k+ only)</del> in the question [Stack Overflow is overrun with bullies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170301/178187) has been deleted. I realize that my answer is not popular (I got a bunch of downvotes), but I have reread the FAQ and searched meta about this topic and I don't think there is any reason to delete it.

Of course, I could be overlooking something in my answer that makes it a bad answer that should be deleted. If that is the case, I'll be grateful to anybody who points me that.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't see your deleted answer either, otherwise you'd post a helpful reference here for people who are <10K, right? =D

Comment: @J.Steen I can see it. I posted a link to the question instead because I thougt that a link to the answer would not work for people with less than 10K reputation. Was I wrong?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, at second glance the answer (imho) is terrible, but that should not have resulted in deletion. Sorry about that one.

Comment: @J.Steen users (maybe over a minimal rep threshold) can see their own deleted answers; they can't see their own deleted questions though. This was like that since the beginning as far as I know.

Comment: @Pablo What I meant was, since a *lot* of people are <10K, how are we supposed to come with constructive critique on why, if we can't see the answer in question (hah)? Or did you not intend for anyone but >10K to have an opinion? It'd be nice to include the answer here for reference since it can't (couldn't) be seen by everyone. =)

Comment: @psubsee2003: Confused whether to remove 10K only or not. You did it right. :)

Comment: @hims056 I almost removed it, then I decided to strike it out... but since I don't know HTML, it took me 5 minutes to remember which tag was appropriate.  Most complicated simple edit I've ever made.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - [This may help you!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/187824)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Agreed. Your answer, however unpopular, was not off-topic or junk so I voted to undelete it.

It contributed to the discussion, if only to show that the community strongly disagrees with the opinion posted.

Comment: It's now undeleted. Not sure why it was deleted; certainly (I hope) not because people disagreed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber we can ask those who deleted what made them reach this decision.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Bart already said sorry; that's plenty I'd say.

Comment: @shawiz I think this question itself is as close as we can come to doing that. Not sure if the delete voter(s) will reply

Comment: @Martijn yup, agreed. We are all human. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't precisely recall why. But reading through the answer I'm thinking *"not true, not true, wrong, wrong, poor list of examples all on their way to be closed...etc."*. That might well have lead me to vote for deletion, which I admittedly shouldn't have. That said, seems the question won't be around much longer anyway.

Comment: @mart oh, it didn't occur to me Bart was apologizing for voting to delete!

Comment: @AndrewBarber: His vote was the 3rd and last. You can see the list in the [post history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/170304/revisions) if you care. :-)

Comment: @Bart cheers, must admit sometimes I fall into this same behavior.

Comment: It contributed to the site a lot by pointing out 7 bad un-closed questions that are now all closed, and proving the broken windows theory by trying to use bad questions to justify other bad questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for that info! Unfortunately, I was on mobile at the time...